# Could lead be radioactive?

Tags: radioactivity

It was recently discovered in 2003 that Bismuth is radioactive, although it's most stable isotope has a half life orders of magnitudes over the age of the universe. Bismuth has no stable isotopes. Is it possible that all of the 4 stable isotopes of lead are not stable? Or is there some "law" stating that lead is not radioactive?

Comment: There are some theories that protons decay, putting all elements at risk.

Comment: The way to tell would be to check the Q values for alpha and beta decay, and see whether the error bars are consistent with zero. This is certainly not the case with, e.g., 208Pb.